# Using PHP inside a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using the jQuery countdown plugin to have a timer on my website
http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html

I am using an API from SportsRadar to list some fixtures that has the dates on

```
<?php echo date("Y/d/m/ - H:i", strtotime($nextMatch['KickOff'])); ?>
```

this will output as `23/04/2015 - 20:00`

In the Countdown plugin their function is the following

```
<script>
    var matchDay = new Date();
    matchDay = new Date(2015, 04-1, 22, 20, 0, 0);
</script>
```

I'm just looking to know how would I add that PHP echo into that JavaScript function? Is it even possible?

Comment: If you willing to force your users to install PHP in their browsers, it is technically possible. But noone will do it.

Comment: you can, but the php code would run **ONCE**, on the server, and its output would become part of the JS code. you cannot mix php and javascript and have both execute at the same time. it's just not posssible. PHP is server-side only, JS is (usually) client-side only.

Comment: you need to convert the date in a format the script recognizes , then use  `matchDay = new Date(<?php echo $myDate;?>); `

Comment: Nah, it's not possible. Javascript happens on clientside (mostly) and PHP on the serverside (mostly). What you can do is to put the PHP in a REST api on the server and retrieve the result in an AJAX call when initializing the js script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an use something like:

```
var matchDay = new Date(<?php $time = strtotime($nextMatch['KickOff']); 
echo date("Y", $time) . "," . date("m", $time) . "," .
    date("m", $time) . "," . date("H", $time) . "," .
    date("i", $time);
?>, 0, 0);
```

Or you an parse date in JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

PHP function `strtotime()` gives you the number of seconds since 1970. You can use this information to initialize a javascript `Date` object. However, javascript expects the number of milliseconds since 1970, thus you ought to multiply the value by 1000:

```
<script>
    var matchDay = new Date(<?php echo strtotime($nextMatch['KickOff'])*1000;?>);
</script>
```

Now you know when the match will take place (in javascript), and you can use it to initialize a countdown or whatever else you want to do with this information.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server-side and will run once. JS is much unlike this. If you need the JS to call a PHP script, consider making an AJAX call. Looking at your goals, however, this seems a tad unnecessary. If all you want is to echo data, you can use JS to update HTML elements on the page instead. That I believe would be the simple solution for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

By doing this it worked fine

```
<script>
var matchDay = new Date();
    matchDay = new Date('<?php echo date("Y", strtotime($nextMatch['KickOff'])); ?>', '<?php echo date("m", strtotime($nextMatch['KickOff'])); ?>'-1, '<?php echo date("d", strtotime($nextMatch['KickOff'])); ?>', '<?php echo date("H", strtotime($nextMatch['KickOff'])); ?>','<?php echo date("i", strtotime($nextMatch['KickOff'])); ?>');
</script>
```